# Mahout Recommendation performance issues

Tags: performance, mahout, mahout-recommender

I have been working with Mahout to create a recommendation engine based on the following data:

- 100k users
- 10k items
- 4M ratings

I'm running it on a Tomcat with the following JVM arguments :

```
-Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -da -dsa -XX:NewRatio=9 -server
```

Recommendations took about 6s, it seems slow ! How could I improve Mahout performances ?

I'm using the following code :

This part is run once at startup :

```
JDBCDataModel jdbcdatamodel = new MySQLJDBCDataModel(dataSource);
dataModel = new ReloadFromJDBCDataModel(jdbcdatamodel);

ItemSimilarity similarity = new CachingItemSimilarity(new EuclideanDistanceSimilarity(model), model);
SamplingCandidateItemsStrategy strategy = new SamplingCandidateItemsStrategy(10, 5);
recommender = new CachingRecommender(new GenericItemBasedRecommender(model, similarity, strategy, strategy));
```

And, for every user request I do :

```
recommender.recommend(userId, howMany);
```

Comment: The bottleneck is the database access

Comment: @JulianOrtega `ReloadFromJDBCDataModel` loads datamodel from the database into memory so this takes time only once, or I'm missing something ?

Comment: Well, since you didn't actually share the code that generates the recommendations, I had to take a guess

Comment: @JulianOrtega Sorry for the imprecision, I edited my post to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach. Use a nightly job, to pre-calculate recommendations for ALL users, and load results nightly into MySQL table. That will make showing the recommendations nothing more than a simple DB call.

Since you have 10K items, for calculating recommendations for a single user mahout has to internally multiply (10k x 10K) matrix with another (10K X 1) matrix. And 6 seconds seems quite fast considering the size. [Reference](http://www.slideshare.net/vangjee/a-quick-tutorial-on-mahouts-recommendation-engine-v-04)

Now if you use the RecommenderJob on hadoop and AWS EMR, it will take ~ <10 mins to process data on your scale. Or you can do the same job in a non-distributed way, by simply using a loop and pre-calculating for all users sequentially. The downside is that your recommendations are always behind by 1 day or 6 hours or whatever frequency you choose for job.

Comment: Good idea, but what if I have to recommend based on what page user is just watching?

Comment: Since he is using `ItemSimilarity`, you show the items similar to what page the user just opened. In case you need a UserSimilarity model - then this kind of batched offline approach is not so useful - consider streaming than batched approach